# How to steady position of featured image in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, header, wordpress-featured-image

I have a problem with featured image in Wordpress. When I add featured image for page header and after that I scroll down this image is not stable - it changes position as I scroll down a page (simultaneously). I have no idea how to make this image stable (the same like "backgroud: fixed"). The result I expect is to scroll down the page without moving image in header (it should change the content of image but not position of entire image).

My wordpress theme: Hestia.

What can i do to solve this problem?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: May be you are looking for background-attachment: fixed;

Comment: I take it into account but I have no idea where exacly I need to put this line in Wordpress? I mean which part of css is responsible for featured image in Hestia theme? I used featured image when I create new page and it is one of the functions that offers wordpress but where it is in css code?